# How to change content with <router-outlet> on non-main page?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to have header, footer and home-news-page when I go to my homepage. And so when I click on the some link on my header, the home-news-page has changed.
My routing now looks like this:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
  path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
    { path: '/sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
    { path: '/sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
  ]
},
{ path: '404', component: Page404Component },

{ path: '**', redirectTo: '404'},
];
```

In the html of my app.component, I only have a `routing-outlet`.
My home-page looks like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

header and footer are displayed, and when I click on a link, the content is redrawn as needed. But by default, the component `HomeNewsComponent` should be preferred and I do not know how to do it.
I understand that this should be done in routing.module. I tried somehow as `path: '', component: HomeNewsComponent`, but then I only show the news without header and footer.
I would be very grateful if someone tells me how to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not getting your explanations. If you want HomeNewsComponent to be displayed on the path `''`, then why did you configure that route to have HomeComponent, and not HomeNewsComponent?

Comment: when I write `path: ', component: HomeNewsComponent` instead of `path:' ', component: HomeComponent` displays news but does not display header and footer

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible, since they're in your app component template, and that template is always displayed. You'll need to post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as a stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, I should write like this:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeNewsComponent },
    { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
    { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
  ]
  },
  { path: PAGE_404, component: Page404Component },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: PAGE_404 },
];
```

Thank you to all who responded !!!

Answer (score 0):

in your HomeComponent this should be in it instead of your app component.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

for your app component you can just have your home component

```
<app-home></app-home>
```

Comment: I added to my app.component: `<app-home></app-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. my home.component looks like this: `<app-header></app-header><router-outlet></router-outlet><app-footer></app-footer>`. and my routing.module - `path: '', component: HomeNewsComponent, children...`. Now I see my header, footer and news, but when I click on any links in my header, I do not redraw the page, although url in the browser adds

Comment: remove <router-outlet></router-outlet> from you app component.

Comment: I removed <router-outlet> from my app component, but it did not help

Comment: strange. it should work.
read this https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html